# In angular.js , Is function call without () different from call with()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I write some example code about `$timeout` service.

```
var myModule = angular.module('timerTest',[]);


        myModule.controller('counting',function($scope,$timeout)
        {
            var timerObject;
            var count =0;

            var countTime = function()
            {
                count++;
                console.log(count);
                $scope.value = count;
                timerObject = $timeout(countTime,1000);
            };

            $scope.startTimer = function()
            {
                console.log('timer start!');
                $timeout(countTime,1000);
            };

            $scope.endTimer = function()
            {
                console.log('End Timer');
                $timeout.cancel(timerObject);
            };

        });
```

In that code at `countTime` function, when I wrote

```
timerObject = > $timeout(countTime(),1000);
```

It calls `countTime()` very fast so It will make callstack overflow.
But when I wrote

```
timerObject = $timeout(countTime,1000);
```

It works perfectly. Is any different from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timerObject = $timeout(countTime(),1000)` immediately calls `countTime` on that line, and passing the *result* of this into `$timeout`. Whenever you put parentheses after a function name, it means you're calling the function right there and then - since you're doing this in every iteration of your function, it's causing it to endlessly repeat, hence the stack overflow.

`timerObject = $timeout(countTime,1000)`, on the other hand, passes the `countTime` function itself into `$timeout` - this is the correct way to use the service, and will cause `$timeout` to call `countTime` after approximately 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you for perfectly answer!

Comment: @JaeyoungLee - Glad I could help! I feel like this trips people up pretty often.